# NRPE status message

Tags: jmeter, nagios, nrpe

I there a way to return status message along with status code.
Here is an example in my python script how i return status code but not message:
    def checkResults(): 
    if not os.path.exists(jmeter_run_log) :
        print "Status: Unknown. Error processing jmeter results file. Results file doesn't exist by % path." % jmeter_run_log
        sys.exit(3);

```
numberOfFailures = 0
try:
    fileHandler = open(jmeter_run_log, 'r')     
    #Check for failing requests
    for line in fileHandler :
        if line.split(jmeter_result_delimiter)[7] == "false":
            numberOfFailures += 1

    fileHandler.close()     
except IOError, (errno, strerror):
    print "Status: Critical. CRITICAL - reading jmeter results file failed with error: %s" %(strerror)
    sys.exit(2) 

if numberOfFailures > 0 :
    print "Status: Critical. Number of failure requests = %s " % numberOfFailures
    #sendNotificationEmail("Status: Critical. Number of failure requests = %s " % numberOfFailures)
    sys.exit(2)     
else: 
    print "Status: OK"
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. NRPE will already return both whatever you output to stdout as the return status message, and also sends along the exit code as the check result status. 0=OK, 1=WARN, 2=CRIT, 3=UNKNOWN.

So both your first example and code sample are already returning status strings along with status code. Am I missing something?